# Supremum and infimum of a rational set bounded by irrational numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, supremum-and-infimum

Let $S = \left\{x \in \mathbb{Q} \mid 1 \leqslant {x}^2 \leqslant 29 \right\}$

What can we say about the supremum and infimum of this set? Would it be non-existent?

Would it be correct to say the following?

Suppose $ \sup  S < \sqrt{29} $ then $ \exists x \in S $ such that $ x > \sup S$

Therfore $ \sqrt{29} \leqslant \sup S$

But on the other hand $\sup S > \sqrt{29}$ then $\exists x \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $ x < \sup S$

Therefore $\sup S \leqslant \sqrt{29}$

Therefore $\sup S $ can only be equal to $\sqrt{29}$

However $\sqrt{29} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ therefore $\sqrt{29} \notin S$

Therefore there can not be a supremum to this set.

(I am assuming the supremum of a set must belong to the set. Is this correct?)

Comment: No, the supremum of a set does not necessarily belong to the set. The supremum of the your set is indeed $\sqrt{29}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The supremum, or least upper bound, of a set need not be elements of the set (and for open sets they *never* are).

Example.  Let $T = (0,1)$.  Then $\sup T = 1 \not \in S$.  That's it.

So in your set, $\sup S = \sqrt{29} \not \in S$.  That's it.

....

Okay, but listen up, this is *important*.  If your universal space is $\mathbb Q$ or some other space.  Then $\sqrt{29}$ will not exist in your *space*.  So we would say in the space of the rationals $S$ does not have a least upper bound.

We say $\mathbb Q$ does not have the "least upper bound property" because it is possible for there to exist sets that are bounded above but that do not have a supremum.  However if your *space* is a *different* set of points and is such a space where *every* set that is bounded above *must* have a least upper bound.  Then we say that space has the "least upper bound property".

Now the *entire* point of the real numbers and the entire reason for the existence of irrational number is that $\mathbb Q$ does *not* have the least upper bound property, but $\mathbb R \supset \mathbb Q$ is an extension of $\mathbb Q$ that *DOES* have the least upper bound property.

**And the irrational numbers are nothing more or less than the least upper bounds of bounded sets of rational numbers that do not have a rational least upper bound.**

So your set $S$ does not have a rational least upper bound.  So it *must* have an *irrational* least upper bound.  And it does.  It is $\sqrt{29}$.

And every irrational number (indeed every real number) is the least upper bound of some set of rational numbers.

.....

Indeed we can actually say:  Let $x \in \mathbb R$ and let $S =\{q\in \mathbb Q| q<x\}$; then $\sup S = x$.

Period.  That is always true.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the set of rational numbers 
$$\{ r \in \mathbb{Q} \mid r \ge 1 \text{ and } r^2 \le 29\}$$

The supremum of the set equals $\sqrt{29}$. Perhaps it is more interesting to show that there does not exist a supremum of this set in $\mathbb{Q}$. That is in some way obvious. But we may still play with it and show the following:

1. $S$ does not have a largest element.
2. While $S$ has majorants in $\mathbb{Q}$ ( for instance $6$), it does not have a smallest majorant in $\mathbb{Q}$.
3. Let $r = \frac{m}{n}$ in $S$. We have $\left( \frac{m}{n}\right)^2 \le 29$, so $29 n^2 - m^2 \ge 0$. Some number theory shows that we cannot have equality. So $29 n^2 - m^2 \ge 1$. Rewrite it as 
   $$(\sqrt{29} n - m)(\sqrt{29}n + m) \ge 1 \\
   \sqrt{29}n - m \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{29}n + m} \\
   \sqrt{29} - \frac{m}{n} \ge \frac{1}{n^2( \sqrt{29}+ \frac{m}{n})}\ge \frac{1}{n^2 \cdot 2 \sqrt{29}} > \frac{1}{12 n^2}$$

We can rephrase this as follows:

If $\frac{m}{n} \in S$ then $\frac{m}{n} + \frac{1}{12 n^2} \in S$. So clearly $S$ does not have a largest element.

2. From the above, the set rationals so that $t \ge s$ for all $s \in S$ is
   $$T = \{ t \in \mathbb{Q} \mid t \ge 0 \text{ and } t^2 > 29 \}$$

Let $ \frac{m}{n}\in T$. In a similar way as above we can show that $\frac{m}{n}- \frac{1}{2 m n} \in T$. Conclusion: the set $T$ does not have a smallest element.

We conclude that $S$ does not have a supremum in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: "We conclude that S does not have a supremum in Q."  The key words being "in $\mathbb Q$".  $S$ does indeed have a supremum in $\mathbb R$.  Indeed *every* bounded set in $\mathbb R$ has a supremum.  That's actually the definition of $\mathbb R$.  So if $S$ does not have a supremum in $\mathbb Q$ then it does have an irrational supremum in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @fleablood: Correct!   That is the magic of $\mathbb{R}$. Thanks for pointing it out.